# class.upload error preg_match()

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use `class.upload` Version 0.32 and it works correctly on my localhost server, but it does not work on my web server.

The web server log file shows this error:

```
PHP Warning:  preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at offset 7 in.
```

**PHP version on web server:** 5.4.39

**PHP version on localhost:** 5.5.15

```
if (preg_match("/^([\.-\w]+)\/([\.-\w]+)(.*)$/i", $this->file_src_mime)) {
    $this->file_src_mime = preg_replace("/^([\.-\w]+)\/([\.-\w]+)(.*)$/i", '$1/$2', $this->file_src_mime);
    $this->log .= '-&nbsp;MIME validated as ' . $this->file_src_mime . '<br />';
} else {
    $this->file_src_mime = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the dash:

```
/^([\.\-\w]+)\/([\.\-\w]+)(.*)$/i
```

or put it at the end or begining of the character class

```
/^([-\.\w]+)\/([-\.\w]+)(.*)$/i
```

and the dot doesn't need to be escaped nor the case insensitive :

```
/^([_.\w]+)\/([-.\w]+)(.*)$/
```